# How to import dbf file data to phpMyAdmin (Mysql server)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, converters, dbf

I have input as .dbf file n i wanted to import that file in my phpMyAdmin (Mysqlserver) with table structure n also with data. I m platform windows zendserver as webserver n php. So is there any best possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with DBF Commander Pro.

At first, configure the connection string (click Connect button in order to check the connection). Then, select the destination table of your MySQL database from the dropdown list. After that, click Export button. You also can execute this operation via command-line interface or BAT file.

More info you can find [here](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file.html#ImpExpDBMS).